# can we solve dynamic knapsack problem using Memoization approach?

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

As we know Dynamic programming has two techniques.

1. Bottom up dynamic programming approach.
2. Top down memoization approach

Normally dynamic knapsack problem is solved using Bottom up dynamic programming approach.can we solve dynamic knapsack problem using Memoization approach?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using this approach? Were you successful?

Comment: yes I tried it with bottom up dynamic approach and It was successful.It gives 0(nW) time complexity (n=number of items,W=knapsack limit)

Comment: How does the other approach compare? What does it give?

Comment: According to this image memoization technique filling the table recursively by results of earlier calls.So can we develop knapsack problem using that technique

Comment: In bottom up approach- Yes.It is working. suppose that name of the 2D array is V. Then v[n][w] gives the correct answer.(doesn't need to full the knapsack)

Comment: In Top Down approach? I am not sure what you are asking about. So you have working isea and want to check whether it is indeed working?

Comment: I tried with iterative dynamic programming(bottom up approach). It calculates the answers for all the sub-problems and then calculate the final answer from sub-problems. It's time complexity is 0(nw). But memoization approach(top-down) doesn't calculate answers for all the sub-problems. It calculates answers for sub-problems if those are  needed.(doesn't find answers for all sub problems). I didn't try it with  memoization.And  I want to know whether memoization approach is working for the knapsack problem.